# On query equally powerful oracles?

Tags: oracle-machines, oracles

1. If $\mathcal C=\mathcal D$ then does $\mathcal A^\mathcal C=\mathcal A^\mathcal D$ hold ($\mathcal C^A=\mathcal D^A$ need not hold)? The class $\mathcal A$ could query same for $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ since $\mathcal C=\mathcal D$ as languages. Correct? Is there a counterexample?
2. If $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal D$ then does $\mathcal A^\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal A^\mathcal D$ hold ($\mathcal C^A\subseteq\mathcal D^A$ need not hold)? The class $\mathcal A$ could query same for $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ since $\mathcal C$ is in $\mathcal D$ and simulate $\mathcal A^\mathcal C$ with $\mathcal A^\mathcal D$. Correct?

Comment: If a=b then f(a) = f(b), provided f is a well-defined function. I don't understand what the question here is.

Comment: @Raphael So there are no counterexamples?

Comment: Working as oracles, $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equal as two sets of languages, instead of 'equal in power' of some models of computation.

Comment: @WillardZhan so  $\mathcal A^\mathcal C=\mathcal A^\mathcal D$?